# How would I go about outputting the output from ALL of the above code?

Tags: c++, text-files

Basically I want an exact copy of the code that appears in the console window to also be outputted to a txt file..

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Initialising gotoxy Comand
void gotoxy(int col, int row)
 {
  COORD coord;
  coord.X = col;
  coord.Y = row;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
 }

int main()

 {

  char name1[20], name2[20], name3[30], name4[20];

  int funcNum = 0;
  int n1Nv, n1Mv, n1SEv, n1SWv;
  int n2Nv, n2Mv, n2SEv, n2SWv;
  int n3Nv, n3Mv, n3SEv, n3SWv;
  int n4Nv, n4Mv, n4SEv, n4SWv;
  int n1Total, n2Total, n3Total, n4Total, perTotal;

  double n1Per, n1PerTotal;
  double n2Per, n2PerTotal;
  double n3Per, n3PerTotal;
  double n4Per, n4PerTotal;
  double maxVote;

    //Introduction
    cout << "================================================================================";
    cout << "                              Ballot Results" << endl;
    cout << "                               Version 2.1" << endl;
    cout << "                          Created by Team b0nkaz" << endl;
    cout << "================================================================================" << endl;

    //Candidate Identification
    cout << "Enter the candidates running for president" << endl << endl;

    //cin.getline (workaround,30); //**

    cout << "Candidate One: ";
    cin.getline (name1,20);

    cout << "Candidate Two: ";
    cin.getline (name2,20);

    cout << "Candidate Three: ";
    cin.getline (name3,20);

    cout << "Candidate Four: ";
    cin.getline (name4,20);
    cout << " " << endl;

    //Separator
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "Input vote numbers from each region pressing enter after each input:" << endl << endl;

    //Separator
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    //Input Table
    //Regions
    gotoxy(22,19);
    cout << "North" << endl;
    gotoxy(31,19);
    cout << "Midlands" << endl;
    gotoxy(43,19);
    cout << "South East" << endl;
    gotoxy(57,19);
    cout << "South West" << endl;
    gotoxy(69,19);
    cout << "|  Total" << endl;
    cout << "_____________________________________________________________________|__________" << endl;
    gotoxy(69,21);
    cout << "|";
    gotoxy(69,22);
    cout << "|";
    gotoxy(69,23);
    cout << "|";
    gotoxy(69,24);
    cout << "|";
    gotoxy(69,25);
    cout << "|";
    gotoxy(69,25);
    cout << "|";
    gotoxy(69,26);
    cout << "|";
    gotoxy(69,27);
    cout << "|";
    gotoxy(69,28);
    cout << "|";
    gotoxy(69,29);
    cout << "|";

    //Candidates
    gotoxy(0,22);
    cout << name1;
    gotoxy(0,24);
    cout << name2;
    gotoxy(0,26);
    cout << name3;
    gotoxy(0,28);
    cout << name4;
    //Equals
    cout << endl;
    cout << "_____________________________________________________________________|__________" << endl;


    //Vote Input
    //North
    gotoxy(22,22);
    cin >> n1Nv;
    gotoxy(22,24);
    cin >> n2Nv;
    gotoxy(22,26);
    cin >> n3Nv;
    gotoxy(22,28);
    cin >> n4Nv;

    //Midlands
    gotoxy(31,22);
    cin >> n1Mv;
    gotoxy(31,24);
    cin >> n2Mv;
    gotoxy(31,26);
    cin >> n3Mv;
    gotoxy(31,28);
    cin >> n4Mv;

    //South East
    gotoxy(43,22);
    cin >> n1SEv;
    gotoxy(43,24);
    cin >> n2SEv;
    gotoxy(43,26);
    cin >> n3SEv;
    gotoxy(43,28);
    cin >> n4SEv;

    //South West
    gotoxy(57,22);
    cin >> n1SWv;
    gotoxy(57,24);
    cin >> n2SWv;
    gotoxy(57,26);
    cin >> n3SWv;
    gotoxy(57,28);
    cin >> n4SWv;

    //Total Votes
    //Name1
    gotoxy(72,22);
    n1Total = n1Nv + n1Mv + n1SEv + n1SWv;
    cout << n1Total;

    //Name2
    gotoxy(72,24);
    n2Total = n2Nv + n2Mv + n2SEv + n2SWv;
    cout << n2Total;

    //Name3
    gotoxy(72,26);
    n3Total = n3Nv + n3Mv + n3SEv + n3SWv;
    cout << n3Total;

    //Name4
    gotoxy(72,28);
    n4Total = n4Nv + n4Mv + n4SEv + n4SWv;
    cout << n4Total << endl << endl << endl;

    //Percentage Calculation
    perTotal = n1Total + n2Total + n3Total + n4Total;

    //Candidate One
    n1Per = n1Total*100;

    n1PerTotal = n1Per/perTotal;

    //Candidate Two
    n2Per = n2Total*100;

    n2PerTotal = n2Per/perTotal;

    //Candidate Three
    n3Per = n3Total*100;

    n3PerTotal = n3Per/perTotal;

    //Candidate Four
    n4Per = n4Total*100;

    n4PerTotal = n4Per/perTotal;

    cout << "Please wait for calculation..." << endl << endl;

    //Spinning Loading Line
    //std::cout << '-' << std::flush;
    //for(;;)

        //{
            //Sleep(100);
            //std::cout << "\b\\" << std::flush;
            //Sleep(100);
            //std::cout << "\b|" << std::flush;
            //Sleep(100);
            //std::cout << "\b/" << std::flush;
            //Sleep(100);
            //std::cout << "\b-" << std::flush;
        //}

    //Sleeping Program
    Sleep(1500); //1.5 secs

    //Total Output
    cout << "Candidate percentage:" << endl << endl;

    //Converting To One Decimal Place
    cout << fixed;
    std::cout.precision(1);

    //Vote Percentages
    cout << name1 << " = " << n1PerTotal << "%" << endl;
    cout << name2 << " = " << n2PerTotal << "%" << endl;
    cout << name3 << " = " << n3PerTotal << "%" << endl;
    cout << name4 << " = " << n4PerTotal << "%" << endl << endl;;

        //Calculating Winnner
        maxVote=n1PerTotal;
        if (n2PerTotal>maxVote)
        maxVote=n2PerTotal;
        if (n3PerTotal>maxVote)
        maxVote=n3PerTotal;
        if (n4PerTotal>maxVote)
        maxVote=n4PerTotal;

    //Separator
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    //Sleeping Program
    Sleep(1500); //1.5 secs

    if(maxVote==n1PerTotal)

      {
        cout << "     ***********************************************************************" << endl;
        cout << "        " << name1 << "                                                     " << endl;
        cout << "        is the new president of The British Society of IT Professionals     " << endl; 
        cout << "        with " << n1PerTotal << "% of the vote                              " << endl;
        cout << "     ***********************************************************************" << endl << endl;

    //Separator
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
      }

    else if(maxVote==n2PerTotal)

      {
        cout << "     ***********************************************************************" << endl;
        cout << "        " << name2 << "                                                     " << endl;
        cout << "        is the new president of The British Society of IT Professionals     " << endl; 
        cout << "        with " << n2PerTotal << "% of the vote                              " << endl;
        cout << "     ***********************************************************************" << endl << endl;

    //Separator
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
      }

    else if(maxVote==n3PerTotal)

      {
        cout << "     ***********************************************************************" << endl;
        cout << "        " << name3 << "                                                     " << endl;
        cout << "        is the new president of The British Society of IT Professionals     " << endl; 
        cout << "        with " << n3PerTotal << "% of the vote                              " << endl;
        cout << "     ***********************************************************************" << endl << endl;

    //Separator
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
      }

    else if(maxVote==n4PerTotal)

      {
        cout << "     ***********************************************************************" << endl;
        cout << "        " << name4 << "                                                     " << endl;
        cout << "        is the new president of The British Society of IT Professionals     " << endl; 
        cout << "        with " << n4PerTotal << "% of the vote                              " << endl;
        cout << "     ***********************************************************************" << endl << endl;;

    //Separator
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
      }

cout << "Press any key to exit..." << endl;

    getch();

//system("pause");
}
```

I am using MS Visual Studio 2010 and any help would be great! Please note I am still very new to C++.

**EDIT** I would like to be able to see the output in CMD as well as have a separate txt file with the same output code. Everything that is displayed in the CMD window also copied into the txt file.

Comment: from the command line, run "myapp.exe > myoutput.txt" - this will capture the console output text and redirect it to a file.

Comment: You probably want to use `tee` instead of just redirecting the output. If you just redirect the output, you won't be able to see the result on screen to run the program interactively. `tee` splits the output to go to two places, in this case the console *and* a file.

Comment: @JerryCoffin could you explain more about `tee` please?

Comment: [man tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee). That will still only show the output from the code though, not the input you provide to your program.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I need it to be able to show input & output, just an exact copy of what is in the CMD window..

Comment: @blanksby: for that, about your best bet is probably to just set up a large buffer in your cmd window, then copy-n-paste from there.

Comment: @JerryCoffin How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

use an ofstream operator as such.
For some reason I can't seem to find the comment button or I would be involved in the discussion above... but I've edited my code below to reflect what seem to be some concerns of yours.

```
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

ofstream fout;
fout.open("data.txt"); //Will create a new file if one is not already in existence
                       //You can put a static filename here or have them enter a string
                       //If you use a custom string your input will be "fout.open(STRING.c_str());
fout<<"Used exactly like cout from this point on";

fout.close(); //When you are done using it to close the file
}
```

I chose to name my ofstream operator fout because (while this is not always good to do) this way you can quickly change all of your cout's to fout's, or replicate them.
If the user enters a value and you want to spit it back out as well, you can use the ofstream operator after every cin.

You can find more information about ofstream [here...](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/)

Hope this helped!

Comment: I don't believe he wants to replace the `cout` statements in a console app where it prompts the user. However he could use file streams.

Comment: I'm suggesting that he could use these in addition. Replicating all of his cout statements as file streams.   Edited it to make it more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from outside of the application using `tee`.  `tee` takes the output of a program and splits it into two streams (e.g. one to stdout and one to a file).  Unfortunately, Windows doesn't come with a `tee` command but there are [many implementations](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=win32+tee+command) available.

If you want this to happen from within your program you can do the equivalent of `tee` using a custom `ofstream`.  [This article](http://wordaligned.org/articles/cpp-streambufs) explains how.

Comment: Could you explain to me how I would implement a custom `ofstream` into my existing code? The article link is a little confusing for me.

Comment: You copy the `teebuf` and `teestream` classes into your code, then use the sample code (which includes the line `teestream tee(std::cout, log);`) to create a `teestream` called `tee`.  Then, instead of using `cout`, use `tee` throughout your code.

Comment: Could you please show me an example, I am lost.. There of lots of different classes with `teebuf` and `teestream`.

Comment: Just use the classes from the section **Tee streams**.